# UIImagepicker Controller not working on touch but only on swpie

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios9, uiimagepickercontroller

In my code , uiimagepickerviewcontroll is not selecting image on touch , it selects image either on swipe on the image or very long press.

I've not added any special code below is the code I've used.

```
        self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        _imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        _imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        _imagePickerController.delegate = self;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

if any one have any solution , please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try presenting the picker instead of pushing it.You should always present a navigation controller, but not push it.

Comment: Hey Teja, I've also tried with that option, but not working.

Comment: Strange that never happened to me. Where are you calling this code ?

Comment: For me also this is first time, this issue never happened. I am calling it in an IBOutlet method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, try this way, working always correct for me:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*) kUTTypeImage];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum ;
_libraryImagePickerController = imagePicker;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this issue came, but I found only 1 solution, created a new project and copied whole code to the new one.

Issue was automatically resolved.